# Dynamically add tabs to TabControl container

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a form in which I would like to be able to add tabs dynamically through the use of a button (much like the buttons most modern browsers have for adding tabs). These tabs should also contain a text box which is stretched to the individual tab's width and height upon creation.

I apologise for the lack of code but besides instantiating a TabControl container within a Form class, I have no clue as to what I should do next.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you need is to call the `Add` method on the `TabControl.TabPages` collection, then add other controls to that TabPage, like so:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tp = new TabPage("Test");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tb.Multiline = true;

        tp.Controls.Add(tb);


    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to make the button look like a tab (like say, in Chrome)?

Comment: Please open another question with this specific topic. This makes it easier for people searching the site afterward. Cheers.

Comment: @AutomEng: Just have a look at the properties window. You will find a lot of properties affecting the appearance of your controls.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants the button to be placed up beside the tabs, and this requires some dynamic placement of the button, not just some look & feel property. As new tabs get added, the button has to move to the right and so on.

Comment: @LucMorin you're totally right. I'll ask a new question. Cheers!